# Is there a way to set a custom Steam Download speed?

Tags: steam

My internet is 5MB/s, which is exactly one of the steam's download speed option. The next lowest option is 3MB/s.
I.e. I can't choose 5MB/s - it is too high since it spoils my browsing experience while steam is downloading. But 3MB/s is also not good since it is much lower than necessary. Something like 4.5MB/s would be ideal.
Is there a way to do it? A way to edit steam files may be, and to change the default options list?

Comment: Just to clarify question, closest Steam options are 3MB/s and 5MB/s, OP wants something in between

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As of October 7<sup>th</sup>, 2020](https://store.steampowered.com/news/76246/), you can now specify an exact speed simply by inputting the amount you desire.  Go to Steam → Settings → Downloads and in the "Download Restrictions" part of the window, check the "Limit Bandwidth to" checkbox and input the amount you wish (in KB/s).  4500 KB/s would equate to 4.5 MB/s.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I found (and slightly redacted) this solution on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/944919/is-it-possible-to-tweak-steams-download-bandwith-limit-settings/1248699#1248699), which was copied verbatim from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/3vvizg/setting_custom_download_speed_limit/), whence it was sourced from the [Steam community](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/10/828938532786367042/#c619569608530636810):

> - Go into your Steam directory, and open the config
>     directory [*C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\config* by default.]
> - Go into the *config* directory and open the "*config.vdf*" file.
> - Find the `DownloadThrottleKbps` setting, and set it to the desired speed (take
>     the amount in Mb/s you want to set it to, and multiply it by 8000 - e.g. 4.5 Mb/s makes `36000`).
> - Save the file, open Steam, and verify that it is working.

Make sure to set the "*config.vdf*" file to 'Read-only'. Steam changes the file on start-up and exiting (when set to be run as administrator).

[image: Steam with custom download limit]

Note that the file contains more settings, so customizing other settings might require the file to have the 'Read-only' flag disabled.

---

<sup>Works with the [New Steam Library](https://store.steampowered.com/libraryupdate) update</sup>

Comment: I can confirm it works. Thank you.

Comment: Although this setting will be lost if you change the speed. It can also sometimes get lost in a steam update. I wish there was a way to add it to a permanent list of custom speeds.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer by [Joachim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/359077/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-custom-steam-download-speed/359086#359086), I created a little Python script that sets the *DownloadThrottleKbps* in the *config.vdf* file, so you don't need to redo it manually everytime the setting gets overwritten.
Recommended use: create a shortcut to the script with the bandwidth in Kbit/s as first the argument.

Example:
To set a bandwidth limit of 4.5MB/s, in the shortcut's properties, edit the Target of the shortcut as:
*C:\path\to\bandwidth-limit-script.py 36000*

Note 1: Close Steam before running this.

Note 2: I hardcoded the path to *C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\config\config.vdf*, so change that line of code if you've installed Steam to a custom location.

Note 3: I used f-strings so you need [Python](https://www.python.org/) 3.6 or higher.

```
# Set Steam download bandwidth limit (for Windows)

import argparse
from time import sleep

# Config
configpath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\config\\config.vdf"
throttlestr = "DownloadThrottleKbps"

# Make the user at least see error messages when launched from a shortcut
# Please don't judge me for my lazy exceptions XD
try:
    # Parse bandwidth argument
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Set Steam download bandwidth limit in Windows.')
    parser.add_argument('bandwidth', metavar='bandwidth', type=int, nargs=1,
            help='Bandwidth limit in Kbit/s. 0 = no limit.\n\
            Recommended use: create a shortcut to the script with bandwidth as first the argument.')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    bandwidth = args.bandwidth[0]

except:
    input('Press Enter to exit')
    exit()

try:
    # Open config file
    with open(configpath, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.readlines()
    
    # Find DownloadThrottleKbps line
    for n in range(len(contents)):                  # Loop over lines of config
        if throttlestr in contents[n]:              # Check for 'DownloadThrottleKbps'
            contents[n] = f'\t\t\t\t"{throttlestr}"\t\t"{bandwidth}"\n' # Replace line
            break                                   # Exit loop

    # Write new config to file file
    with open(configpath, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(contents)

except:
    input(f'Error during file access of {configpath}\nPress Enter to exit')
    exit()

print(f'Steam bandwidth limit was set to {bandwidth} Kbit/s')
sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from editing the config.vdf file, another option is mentioned on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/fpu7qu/protip_custom_download_limit/):

1. Enable the Steam Console: either start Steam with the *-console* argument or open the link *steam://open/console* in your browser
2. Click on *Console* which appears at the top, right next to your name.
3. Type *set_download_throttle 8000* to set the download limit to 8000Kbit/s = 1MB/s.