# How can I determine steam maximum download speed?

Tags: steam

My ISP provider released a data plan of 1GB, which roughly translates as a download speed of 100mb/s.

As an early adpoter of this ISP, I had too many good experiences with them to trust that they would deliver this download speed. However, to my dismay, I cannot surpass the 60mb/s download speed for steam, other than some random spikes.

After contacting my ISP, they claimed that steam may limit trafic on specific times and that is why I cannot get to my dream download speed.

My router is a Gigabit one, so it can handle the internet speeds.

My speed tests show 1 GB on fast and speedtest.

With all that in mind, is there any way to test or guarantee the max steam download speed?

*I decided to post here instead of superuser because this may be a question of other gamers*

Comment: While this is a more extreme example, Nexus Mods restricts un-subscribed mod downloads to 1mb/s. It's entirely possible that steam does indeed limit your maximum speed, but as to why, is likely unknown.

Comment: I also opened a ticket on steam in case they can answer me about this limits. If I get a response I'll post here

Comment: Sort of related https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/359077/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-custom-steam-download-speed

Comment: 1GB means 100 mb/s? Don't you mean 100MB/s?

Comment: @Mixxiphoid they just have their units backwards, 1 Gb/s is roughly 100 MB/s (125 to be more exact).

Comment: @Moacir what kind of drive do you have? at those speeds its not impossible your disk write speed is the bottleneck.

Comment: I have 500 mbps glassfiber and also never reach higher than 60mbps in steam. It seems like they throtle it, but I got no proof.

Comment: @JBGreen I have a hdd which I use to test the download speed with GTAV, however I got a Kingston SSD which I download Farcry 3, since it has less available space. Both got the same download limitation with ocasional spikes

Comment: Just a quick update, Steam support already answered me twice with a copypasta pointing to their article to check my connectivity instead of answering if they do impose any limit on the download speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steam answered me a minute ago:

[image]

Since this is an official answer, I'll mark my question as answered